# Laravel Validation Unique Rule On Multiple Columns

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation

I have a users table and two columns that are: `email` and `phone`.
In my register and login controller, I wanna make a field unique in both email and phone columns.

```
$data = request()->validate([
   'login' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users,email'],
   'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
]);
```

This is my code and it only checks email column to ensure the value of login field doesn't exist there.
How can I change this rule to check both email and phone columns?

Comment: I finished up making custom validation rule for this use case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make another ‌‌‌‌‌rule‌‌‌‌‌‌‌:‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌

```
$data = request()->validate([
   'login' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users,email','unique:users,phone'],
   'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
]);
```

Comment: But that produces an unnecessary second query, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Dan I think if you pass the value as an array, then it will do a second query too